# Build a Customer Lifetime Value line chart with postgres and chart.io

Tags: sql, postgresql, charts

I need to build a customer lifetime value chart and got stuck on how to do this in plain psql.

[image: a mockup on what it is supposed to look like]

So the idea is to have a line for each day, that shows the average amount customers that signed on that day spend over time.

My tables look like this:

Users

```
id | created_at
1  | 2013-11-01
2  | 2013-11-02
3  | 2013-11-03
4  | 2013-11-03
```

Charges

```
id | created_at | total_amount | user_id
1  | 2013-11-01 | 49.00        | 1
2  | 2013-11-01 | 22.00        | 1
3  | 2013-11-04 | 10.00        | 1
4  | 2013-11-02 | 49.00        | 2
5  | 2013-11-03 | 66.00        | 3
6  | 2013-11-03 | 49.00        | 4
7  | 2013-11-06 | 14.00        | 4
8  | 2013-11-12 | 33.00        | 4
```

We need this to be rendered as a line chart using chart.io. therefore the result table has to look like this:

```
created_at | Layer      | avg_amount
2013-11-01 | 2013-11-01 | 35.50
2013-11-04 | 2013-11-01 | 10.00
2013-11-02 | 2013-11-02 | 49.00
2013-11-03 | 2013-11-03 | 57.50
2013-11-06 | 2013-11-03 | 14.00
2013-11-12 | 2013-11-03 | 33.00
```

'created at' refers to when the charges where made

'Layer' refers to when the user was created

'avg_amount' is the avg total_amount of charges that day for user who signed up on 'created_at'

thanks :)

EDIT: Unfortunately specs changed as marketing saw the graph...they now want the Y axis to never dip. It needs to be [cumulative total of revenue ever created from cohort users]/[all users in cohort]. Therefore the nominator can increase, but the denominator can never decrease.

So the resulting table should look like:

```
created_at | Layer      | cumulative_amount
2013-11-01 | 2013-11-01 | 71.00
2013-11-02 | 2013-11-02 | 49.00
2013-11-03 | 2013-11-03 | 66.00
2013-11-03 | 2013-11-03 | 49.00
2013-11-04 | 2013-11-01 | 81.00
2013-11-06 | 2013-11-03 | 63.00
2013-11-12 | 2013-11-03 | 96.00
```

Thanks so much

Comment: Here's an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6775c) with the test data ready to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few formatting issues that I'm sure you can work out ([here's the SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c6e05/5)), but here's the basic query you want.

```
WITH daily_charges AS (
  SELECT
    sum(total_amount) AS daily_total,
    user_id,
    date_trunc('day', created_at) AS charge_date
  FROM charges
  GROUP BY user_id, created_at
  )
SELECT
  d.charge_date,
  date_trunc('day', u.created_at) AS layer,
  avg(d.daily_total) AS avg_amount
FROM
  daily_charges d
  JOIN users u ON
    (d.user_id=u.id)
GROUP BY charge_date, layer;
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan...this gets me super close, just one issue: Users might have multiple charges per day.

How I understand your query right now, it will takes all charges per user/day and AVG them....which messes up the results :(

Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: Sure, edited the query above and added some test data to my SQLFiddle to show that it works.